# GEO query with multiple conditions

Tags: redis

I'm considering to use Redis for one scenario(for performance and other reasons) which seems to be quite easy to implement using "normal" database,
but I can't figure out how to implement it using Redis:

Lets imagine that I have a bunch of shops, and every shop has coordinates and set of attributes, like "bikes", "cars", "flowers", "groceries":

```
shop1: lon1, lat1, "bikes", "cars"
shop2: lon2, lat2, "flowers", "groceries"
shop3: lon3, lat3, "flowers", "groceries", "cars", "bikes"
...and etc.
```

How do I find in the most efficient way 5 shops closest to some point which have attributes "cars" and "flowers"?

It looks like it's pretty easy to query just all shops nearby some position, but then how can I filter out only shops with specific attributes?

Comment: As far as i understand your question, i think you can call `KEYS doc:*` to get a list of all keys matching your criteria and then get all values in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to create a Set for each category/facet:

```
SADD bikes shop1 shop3
SADD cars shop1 shop3
SADD flowers shop2 shop3
SADD groceries shop2 shop3
```

Perform `GEORADIUS ... STORE <some-temporary-key>` and then you can call `SINTER <some-temporary-key> cars flowers` to answer your query.

Note that "simplest" does not necessarily mean most efficient, but that's a different matter. An alternative is to use [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/).

Comment: Thanks. Will try this!